# Menu disappears when meta_key changed

Tags: pre-get-posts

[Menu disappears example](http://newukhome.qproduction.co.uk/properties/?offers=25&property_price=desc)

I sent you the link in the attachment so you can see that menu disappears on custom filter change below. If you choose ‘most recent’ (that not affects meta_key) menu shows nicely, but if you choose price, all menus disappear.

Here is the code:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'noo_landmark_addon_pre_get_posts' ) ) :

    function noo_landmark_addon_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
        if ( is_admin() ) {
            return $query;
        }
        if ( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_singular ) {
            return;
        }

        /**
         * Set query in archive property
         */
        if ( RP_Property::is_property() ) {

            $args = array();

            /**
             * Check order
             */
            $default_orderby = isset( $query->query_vars[ 'orderby' ] ) ? $query->query_vars[ 'orderby' ] : get_theme_mod( 'noo_property_listing_orderby', 'date' );

            $orderby = isset( $_GET[ 'orderby' ] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_GET[ 'orderby' ] ) : $default_orderby;

            $orderby            = strtolower( $orderby );
            $order              = isset( $query->query_vars[ 'order' ] ) ? $query->query_vars[ 'order' ] : 'DESC';

            $args[ 'orderby' ]  = $orderby;
            $args[ 'order' ]    = $order == 'DESC' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';
            $args[ 'meta_key' ] = '';

            // global filter

            if ( isset($_GET['recent_first']) ) {
                    $args[ 'orderby' ] = 'date';
                    $args[ 'order' ]   = sanitize_text_field($_GET['recent_first']);
            }
            if ( isset($_GET['property_price']) ) {
                    $args[ 'orderby' ]  = 'meta_value_num meta_value';
                    $args[ 'order' ]    = sanitize_text_field($_GET['property_price']);
                    $args[ 'meta_key' ] = 'price';
            }

            $query->set( 'orderby', $args[ 'orderby' ] );
            $query->set( 'order', $args[ 'order' ] );

            if ( isset( $args[ 'meta_key' ] ) && ! empty( $args[ 'meta_key' ] ) ) {
                $query->set( 'meta_key', $args[ 'meta_key' ] );
            }
            if ( isset( $args[ 'meta_value' ] ) && ! empty( $args[ 'meta_value' ] ) ) {
                $query->set( 'meta_value', $args[ 'meta_value' ] );
            }
            if ( isset( $args[ 'meta_query' ] ) && ! empty( $args[ 'meta_query' ] ) ) {
                $query->set( 'meta_query', $args[ 'meta_query' ] );
            }

            /**
             * Set number show posts
             */
            $property_per_page = get_theme_mod( 'noo_property_per_page', 10 );
            $query->set( 'posts_per_page', $property_per_page );
            $query->set( 'post_status', 'publish' );

        }

        /**
         * Set query in archive agent
         */
        if ( RP_Agent::is_archive_agent() ) {
            $agent_per_page = get_theme_mod( 'noo_agent_per_page', 10 );
            $query->set( 'posts_per_page', $agent_per_page );

            $agent_must_has_property = Realty_Portal::get_setting( 'agent_setting', 'agent_must_has_property', false );
            if ( $agent_must_has_property === '1' ) {

                query_posts( 'post_type=noo_agent&posts_per_page=-1' );
                $agent_ids = array();
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                    $agent_id = get_the_ID();
                    $user_id  = RP_Agent::get_id_user( $agent_id );
                    if ( $user_id < 1 ) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    $total_property = count_user_posts( $user_id, 'noo_property' );
                    if ( $total_property > 0 ) {
                        $agent_ids[] = $agent_id;
                    }
                endwhile;
                wp_reset_query();
                $query->set( 'post__in', $agent_ids );
            }
        }
    }

    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'noo_landmark_addon_pre_get_posts' );
endif;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_singular ) {
            return;
}
```

This is the wrong way around - it's actually ensuring that the query is being modified on everything *except* the main query, which is why it's affecting the menus (which are also built using queries).

You need to change it to `if ( !$query->is_main_query() && !$query->is_singular )`

Comment: Thank you for quick response, but now the filter is not working

Comment: Take out the `&& !$query->is_singular`

Comment: Same story. Menu is back but filter is not working https://postimg.org/image/soge6ar0b/